# Python distributed application architecture on constrained corporate environment

Tags: python, architecture, distributed, environment

This is my scenario: I developed a Python desktop application which I use to probe the status of services/DBs on the very same machine it is running on.

My need is to monitor, using my application, two "brother" Window Server 2003 hosts (Python version is 2.5 for both). One of the hosts lies in my own LAN, the other one lies in another LAN which is reachable via VPN.

The application is composed by:

1. A Graphical User Interface (`gui.py`), which provides widgets to collect user inputs and launches the...
2. ...business-logic script (`console.py`), which in turn invokes slave Python scripts that check the system's services and DB usage/accounts status/ecc. The textual output of those checks is then returned back to the GUI.

I used to execute the application directly on each the two machines, but it would be great to turn it into a client/server application, so that:

- users will just be supposed to run the `gui.py` locally
- the `gui.py` will be supposed to communicate parameters to some server remakes of `console.py` which will be running on both of the Windows hosts
- the servers will then execute system checks and report back the results to the client GUIs which will display them.

I thought about two possible solutions:

1. Create a Windows service on each of the Windows hosts, basically executing  `console.py`'s code and waiting for incoming requests from the clients
2. Open SSH connections from any LAN host to the eliged Windows host and directly run `console.py` on it.

I am working on a corporate environment, which has some network and host constraints: many network protocols (like SSH) are filtered by our corporate firewall. Furthermore, I don't have Administration privileges onto the Windows hosts, so I can't install system services on them...this is frustrating!

I just wanted to ask if there is any other way to make `gui.py` and `console.py` communicate over the network and which I did not take into account. Does anyone have any suggestion? Please note that - if possible - I'm not going to ask ICT department to give me Administration privileges on the Windows hosts!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to myself: I found one possible solution..

I'm lucky because the `console.py` script is actually invoking many slave python scripts, each of them performing one single system check via standard third-party command-line tools which can be fired to check features on remote hosts.

Then, what I did was to modify the `gui.py` and `console.py` so that users can parametrically specify on which Windows host the checks must be carried out.
In this way, I can obtain a ditributed application...but I've been lucky, what if one or more of the third-party CL tools did not support remote host features checking?